# aizu online judgeのALDS1_1_Aで答えが合ってるのにWAになってしまう。

Tags: c

C言語で下記を書きました。
手元で実行してる限り合ってるのですが、WAになってしまう...
どこか間違ってる箇所ありますでしょうか。
他の方の回答を落としてローカルで実行結果をファイルにリダイレクトしてdiffしてみても差が無く。

```
#include<stdio.h>

void trace(int r[], int N) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
      printf("%d", r[i]);
      if (i != N - 1) {
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main() {
    
  int r[100];

  int N;
  scanf("%d", &N);
    for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &r[i]);
    }

    trace(r, N);
    int j, i, v; 
    for ( i = 1; i < N ; i++) {
      v = r[i];
      j = i - 1;

      while(v >= 0 && r[j] > v ){
        r[j + 1] = r[j];
        j--;
      }
      r[j + 1] = v;
      trace(r, N);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: もし質問が解決した場合は、一番役に立った回答の横にある灰色のチェックマークをクリックし、[回答を承認済み](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/32986)にしていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while(v >= 0 && r[j] > v ){
>   r[j + 1] = r[j];
>   j--;
> }
> ```

ここだけ見ると`j`の値に制約がありません。そのため`r`の範囲を超えてアクセスしてしまうように見えます。逆に`v`の値は変化しないのでループ毎で`v >= 0`を評価する意義もないはずです。

Comment: あー完全に見落としてました。
まさにそこでした。
ありがとうございます！